# in angular UI collapse ,Initial page load showing div as collapsed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use a collapse model in angular UI

```
<div class="" ng-click="isCollapsed =!isCollapsed" ></div>
```

and in my controller i set the value

```
$scope.isCollapsed = true;
```

but my initial pageload shows  the div as collapsed. I want to hide it initially .Could someone help me with this

Comment: Not really enough code to know what is going on here. You are setting the isCollapsed property to true on load and then not expecting it to be collapsed? - please show code for div that you want to hide \ collapse

Comment: The collapse will be triggered only if a click event is generated..Here in my case it is generated before the click does happens..

Comment: Then, in controller:  $scope.isCollapsed = false;

Comment: I tried that also...but no effect

Comment: are you using ng-show="isCollapsed" on the section you want to toggle display?

Comment: no....that was a mistake on another part of the code...i have resolved it..Any way thanks for your help

Comment: As I said - you need to share more code